# Решение задачи связности методом быстрого объединения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, объединение

Спасибо всем кто зашел сюда и уделил мне время.

Читаю Роберта Седжвика (с++) 2014, стр 31, Лемма 1.2.

Приведен пример решения задачи связности методом быстрого объединения.

```
for(i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]) ;
for(j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]) ;
if(i == j) continue;
id[i] = j;
```

С этим все ясно, далее он пишет о эффективности алгоритма:

> Для M пар из N объектов, когда M > N, решение задачи связности алгоритмом быстрого объединения может потребовать выполнения более чем M N/2 инструкций.

Говорит он про пары M, в их число ведь входят правильные пары и не правильные? Те которые просто поступают на ввод?

> Предположим, что пары вводятся в следующем порядке (1-2 2-3 3-4) итд. После ввода N-1 таких пар мы получим N объектов, принадлежащих к одному множеству,a сформированное алгоритмом быстрого объединения дерево представляет собой прямую линию, где объект N указывает на объект N-1, тот, в свою очередь - на объект N-2, тот на N-3 и тд. Чтобы выполнить операцию поиск для объекта N, программа должна перейти по N-1 указателям. Таким образом, среднее количество указателей, по которым выполняются переходы для первых N пар, равно 
>   (0+1+...(N-1))/N = (N-1)/2

Зачем он находит среднее арифмитическое?!
Он ведь говорит что список построен (1-2 2-3 3-4) и тд, что бы пройти от начала до конца нужно N-1 раз пройти. 
Не понятно что он имеет введу "переходы для ***первых*** N пар"?

> Теперь предположим, что все остальные пары связывают объект N с каким либо другим объектом. Чтобы выполнить операцию поиск для каждой из этих пар требуется перейти, по меньшей мере, по N-1 указателям. Общий итог для M операций поиск при такой последовательности вводимых пар определенно больше MN/2

Что он имеет введу "все ***остальные*** пары", неправильные пары в вводе?
Как он вывел MN/2?

Возможно я где то сглупил, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Говорит он про пары M, в их число ведь входят правильные пары и не правильные? Те которые просто поступают на ввод?

Что такое, в вашем понимании, "неправильные" пары? Нет никакого разделения пар на правильные и нет, есть только вершины и ребра графа.

> Зачем он находит среднее арифмитическое?! Он ведь говорит что список построен (1-2 2-3 3-4) и тд, что бы пройти от начала до конца нужно N-1 раз пройти.

Речь идет, напомню, про оценку времени. Программа выполняет N операций объединения - при этом каждая операция занимает какое-то свое время. Чтобы можно было что-то сказать про время выполнения операции в целом - надо эти значения усреднить. Затем и среднее арифметическое.

> Не понятно что он имеет введу "переходы для первых N пар"?
>   Что он имеет введу "все остальные пары", неправильные пары в вводе? Как он вывел MN/2?

Автор рассматривает такую последовательность пар на входе алгоритма в качестве примера "плохой" последовательности:

1. сначала идет N-1 пара - (1,2), (2,3), ..., (N-1, N);
2. потом идет M-N+1 пара вида (*, N).

Каждая пара обрабатывается приведенным вами алгоритмом. "Переход" - это итерация одного из циклов `for` в первых двух строках.

Так, для пары (4,5) из первого блока придется пройти 4-3-2-1 (5 пока еще ни с кем не связана), всего 3 перехода.

Для пары (4, N) из второго блока придется пройти сначала 4-3-2-1, а потом еще N-(N-1)-...-4-3-2-1, всего N+2 перехода.

Comment: Правильные/неправильные - я так подумал когда прочел "Для M пар из N объектов, когда M > N", он написал ранее что "алгоритм решения задачи связности  никогда не выводит более N-1 пар, поскольку как только он выведет N-1 пару, любая встретившаяся после этого пара, будет уже связная" уже связная - неправильная, "if(i==j) continue;" Cначала N-1 пара - (1,2), (2,3), ..., (N-1, N), потом все "неправильные" связи.

Comment: Зачем находить среднее значение? Укажите пожалуйста, где операции разные? ;c

Comment: Для пары (1,2) не выполняется никаких переходов, для пары (2,3) делается 1 переход, потом 2, 3 и т.д. до N-1 перехода.

Comment: Где 1 переход?  http://savepic.ru/7332262.png Может вы имели введу "синхронизацию" количества итераций между 2мя циклами? Поэтому среднее находится?

Comment: Но ведь в таком примере нет разницы между ними. (посмотрите картинку, пожалуйста)

Comment: Понял, что именно вызвало затруднения. Поменяйте местами числа в парах - тогда все сойдется :)

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы понимаете под "синхронизацией"

Comment: У одного цикла A итераций, у другого B итераций. Между ними среднее арифм? PS: Спасибо что помогаете разобраться :D

Comment: Нет, "между циклами" берется сумма. Среднее берется между разными парами.

Comment: Теперь я все понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Он просто сначала рассмотрел группу первых X union-ов, а затем - группу других Y. Из свойства первой группу он вывел, что число операций для каждого вызова union во второй группе ограничено снизу числом (X - 1), отсюда получил как минимум Y(X - 1) операций. Просто небольшая вольность языка.

UPD: из <s>второго</s> четвертого издания:

> Again, suppose that we use quick-union for the dynamic connectivity
>   problem and wind up with a single component. An immediate implication
>   of PROPOSITION G is that the running time is quadratic, in the worst
>   case. Suppose that the input pairs come in the order 0-1, then 0-2,
>   then 0-3, and o forth. After N - 1 such pairs, we have N sites all in
>   the same set, and the tree that is formed by the quick-union algorithm
>   has height N - 1, with 0 linking to 1, which links to 2, which links
>   to 3, and so forth (see the diagram on the facing page). By
>   PROPOSITION G, the number of array accesses for the union() operation
>   for the pair `0 i` is exactly 2i + 3 (site 0 is at depth i and site i
>   at depth 0). Thus, the total number of array accesses for the find()
>   operations for these pairs is (3 + 5 + 7 + … + 2N + 1) ~ N^2.

Видимо, действительно в первом издании было плохо понятно, поэтому во <s>втором</s> четвертом пример полностью переработали :) Могу лишь посоветовать заказать второе издание, это признанный шедевр.

Comment: В интернете нашел только 2014 года и 2011 года, а какое у вас издание?

Comment: @uskabuska четвертое издание, 2014